# A very simple TODO app's domain model

Tags: clojure, to-do-list

I am currently rewriting a todo app from java to clojure. This is my first "real" clojure project so I'm not sure that what I write is idiomatic clojure code. I have just finished rewriting the domain module and I'd like to know how can I improve on it to have something which is idiomatic.

I had some simple classes in my original java project:

- `Box` <-- Represents a Box in the EisenhowerMatrix
- `BoxBlurbsProvider` <-- provides name and description labels for a Box
- `EisenhowerMatrix` <-- represents the matrix itself
- `Importance` <-- enum holding the possible importance values
- `Urgency` <-- enum holding the possible urgency values
- `Task` <-- represents a Task in an EisenhowerMatrix Box

My original classes are these (note that I omitted documentation from my code):

> ```
> @Getter
> @Builder
> public class Box {
>
>     private final Urgency urgency;
>     private final Importance importance;
>     private final String name;
>     private final String description;
>     private final Set<Task> tasks = new LinkedHashSet<>();
>
>     public void addTask(final Task task) {
>         tasks.add(task);
>     }
>
>     public void removeTask(final Task task) {
>         tasks.remove(task);
>     }
> }
>
> public interface BoxBlurbsProvider {
>     String getNameFor(Urgency urgency, Importance importance);
>     String getDescriptionFor(Urgency urgency, Importance importance);
> }
>
> public class EisenhowerMatrix {
>
>     @Value(staticConstructor = "of")
>     private static class BoxKey {
>         private final Urgency urgency;
>         private final Importance importance;
>     }
>
>     private final Map<BoxKey, Box> boxes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
>
>     @Getter
>     private final String name;
>
>     private EisenhowerMatrix(String name, BoxBlurbsProvider boxBlurbsProvider) {
>         this.name = name;
>         for (Importance importance : Importance.values()) {
>             for (Urgency urgency : Urgency.values()) {
>                 boxes.put(BoxKey.of(urgency, importance), Box.builder()
>                         .importance(importance)
>                         .urgency(urgency)
>                         .name(boxBlurbsProvider.getNameFor(urgency, importance))
>                         .description(boxBlurbsProvider.getDescriptionFor(urgency, importance))
>                         .build());
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static EisenhowerMatrix of(String name, BoxBlurbsProvider boxBlurbsProvider) {
>         return new EisenhowerMatrix(name, boxBlurbsProvider);
>     }
>
>     public List<Box> getBoxes() {
>         return new ArrayList<>(boxes.values());
>     }
>
>     public void addTask(final Urgency urgency, final Importance importance, final Task task) {
>         boxes.get(BoxKey.of(urgency, importance)).addTask(task);
>     }
>
>     public void removeTask(final Task task) {
>         boxes.values().forEach(box -> box.removeTask(task));
>     }
>
>     public List<Task> getTasks() {
>         return boxes.values().stream().flatMap(box -> box.getTasks().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
>     }
> }
>
> public enum Importance {
>     IMPORTANT, NOT_IMPORTANT
> }
>
> public enum Urgency {
>     URGENT, NOT_URGENT
> }
>
> @Data
> @RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
> public class Task {
>     private final String name;
>     private final String description;
> }
> ```

My resulting clojure code is in two namespaces. One for records and one for protocols:

**records.clj:**

```
(ns eisentower.domain.records
  (:use [eisentower.domain.protocols]))

(def urgencies [:urgent :not-urgent])
(def importances [:important :not-important])

(defn- combine-keywords [& keywords]
  (keyword
    (reduce
      (fn [k0 k1] (str (name k0) (name k1)))
      keywords)))

(defrecord Box [urgency importance name description tasks]
  BoxOperations
  (add-task-to-box [box task]
    (update-in box [:tasks] conj task))
  (remove-task-from-box [box task]
    (assoc box
      :tasks
      (remove #(= (:name %) (:name task)) (:tasks box)))))

(defn- create-boxes []
  (for [u urgencies i importances]
    (->Box u i (get-name-for u i) (get-description-for u i) [])))

(defrecord Task [name description])

(defrecord EisenhowerMatrix [boxes name]
  MatrixOperations
  (get-tasks [matrix]
    (into [] (mapcat #(:tasks (val %)) boxes)))
  (get-boxes [matrix]
    (:boxes matrix))
  (add-task-to-matrix [matrix urgency importance task]
    (let [box-key (combine-keywords urgency importance)
          box (get-in matrix [:boxes box-key])]
      (assoc-in matrix [:boxes box-key] (add-task-to-box box task))))
  (remove-task-from-matrix [matrix task]
    (loop [box (:boxes matrix)]
      (if (contains? (:tasks box) task)
        (let [box-key (combine-keywords (:urgency box) (:importance box))]
          (assoc-in matrix [:boxes box-key] (remove-task-from-box box task)))))))

(defn create-matrix [name]
  (->EisenhowerMatrix
    (into {} (map
               (fn [box]
                 {(combine-keywords (:urgency box) (:importance box)) box})
               (create-boxes)))
    name))
```

**protocols.clj:**

```
(ns eisentower.domain.protocols)

(defprotocol BoxBlurbOperations
  (get-name-for [urgency importance])
  (get-description-for [urgency importance]))

(defprotocol MatrixOperations
  (get-tasks [matrix])
  (get-boxes [matrix])
  (add-task-to-matrix [matrix urgency importance task])
  (remove-task-from-matrix [matrix task]))

(defprotocol BoxOperations
  (add-task-to-box [box task])
  (remove-task-from-box [box task]))
```

Some points I'm a bit puzzled with:

- Can it be less verbose?
- Can it be more readable?
- Can I clean it up somehow?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Isn't it too OOP**y**?
- How can it be more idiomatic?

Comment: I assembled [a "microblog" for you about this as a gist](https://gist.github.com/blerou/0606277049dae5582bbe238883e7f39f).

Comment: Since you've used `LinkedHashMap`s and `LinkedHashSet`s in the Java, you might consider for the Clojure version [amalloy/ordered](https://github.com/amalloy/ordered) sets and maps. They too maintain the insertion order of their contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started to write the java example as one-to-one mapping to clojure, but shortly realized that it's not entirely possible. The main reason that the original design is not sound for me.

So I was starting to think about the core concept and that can be summed up in one domain entity: the task.

Let's create a task.

```
(defn create-task
  [name desc urgent? important?]
  {:name name, :description desc, :urgent? urgent?, :important? important?})
```

Of course, it's a bit sloppy, so let's specify it properly. I'm using clojure.spec for this.

```
(s/def ::name (s/and string?
                     (comp not empty?)))
(s/def ::description string?)
(s/def ::urgent? boolean?)
(s/def ::important? boolean?)

(s/def ::task (s/keys :req-un [::name ::description ::urgent? ::important?]))
And let's specify the constructor function itself.

(s/fdef create-task
        :args (s/cat :name ::name, :description ::description, :urgent? ::urgent?, :important? ::important?)
        :ret ::task)
```

The box concept is not necessarily need any implementation. We are interested in the grouped tasks by boxes and this is what the group-by function is for.

```
(defn box-tasks
  [tasks]
  (group-by (fn [{:keys [urgent? important?]}] [urgent? important?]) tasks))

(s/def ::tasks (s/coll-of ::task))
(s/def ::box-key (s/tuple ::urgent? ::important?))
(s/def ::box-tasks (s/map-of ::box-key ::tasks))

(s/fdef box-tasks
        :args (s/cat :tasks ::tasks)
        :ret ::box-tasks)
```

Side note: the ::box-tasks definition is odd, the default generator will generate inconsistent box-keys and tasks for it.

If you really need a matrix, you can define a simple constructor function for it.

```
(defn create-matrix
  [name]
  {:name name, :tasks #{}})

(s/def ::matrix (s/keys :req-un [::name ::tasks]))

(s/fdef create-matrix
        :args (s/cat :name ::name)
        :ret ::matrix)
```

and some basic operations

```
(defn add-task    [m t] (update m :tasks conj t))
(defn remove-task [m t] (update m :tasks disj t))

(s/fdef add-task
        :args (s/cat :matrix ::matrix :task ::task)
        :ret ::matrix)

(s/fdef remove-task
        :args (s/cat :matrix ::matrix :task ::task)
        :ret ::matrix)
```

Comment: Consider `(group-by #(select-keys % [:urgent? :important?]) tasks))`. I'd be forever forgetting the order in the vector.

Comment: `::box-key` defines this, but extracting a `box-key` function would help.

Comment: I think my suggestion resolves the problem you mention of " inconsistent box-keys and tasks".

Comment: Nope. It doesn't matter how you create your keys as far as the spec has no explicit knowledge about the connection between ::box-key and the related ::tasks described in the ::box-tasks spec.

I have no idea it is even possible to describe this situation with spec or your only chance is to simple define a custom generator for it.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by " inconsistent box-keys and tasks". And I thought, wrongly, that `(s/fdef box-tasks ...  :ret ::box-tasks)` was invalid: I had misread the `::box-key` spec. I was able to use the specs  to discover my error.